# Use value of cell as partial argument in A1 notation

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I would like to be able to pass arguments to functions using the values of cells. In this case, I would like to do...

```
=sum('C' + ((E25)+1).toString() + ':' + 'C' + ((F25)+1).toString())
# Arguments passed are the values of the cells E25 and D25, plus one.
```

Is there a built-in way to do this, or will I need to use the Spreadsheet library and write a function to handle it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [=INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) to make the value into a cell reference.

For example `=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&(E2)+1):INDIRECT("D"&F2+2))`

This would first get the value of cell E2 and add 1 to it. That number would be the row number for column C.

The second portion adds 2 to the value of cell F2- giving you the cell D whatever.

Working example [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o2wjQIg2RKvxQ7gkkRuOQljBBp4o5RMGd5jvH6fCTFU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: How do you convert the value of a cell into a string?

Example:

Convert `(E3+1)` and `(F3+1)` to type string for use in indirect.
`=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A", (E3+1), ":", "A", (F3+1))`

Comment: =SUM(INDIRECT("C"&(E2)+1):INDIRECT("D"&F2+2))